# Right click in VS2010 editor (c++) just flashes - no context menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I can build my project just fine, but if I right click to, say, jump to a definition or just pull up a menu I get nothing. If I highlight a variable or method and then right click, then the ide title bar flashes a couple of times, but I never see a menu. I've never seen an error message either which makes it that much hard to diagnose.

C# projects behave just fine. It only seems to affect C++ projects. This also wasn't an issue in VS2008 or 2005.

[Edit: running in Safe Mode gets me what I need.]

Comment: Do you have some kind of plug-in installed, like Visual Assist, that might be causing this? Try running the VS IDE in safe mode with no plug-ins loaded.

Comment: Safe mode seems to do it - the ide starts up much quicker and it behaves sanely with my c++ projects. Thanks! Incidentally, I do have resharper but I disable it any time I'm not in a .Net project - apparently that's not enough.